# I want to split an image using pytorch and save it in a folder

Tags: image-processing, pytorch

I have this image of a flower that I want to split in x*x parts
saying the image is this one
https://purepng.com/photo/6028/nature-flower

How can I do the splitting in pytorch?
I have found opencv code for that, but now I want to do it using torch.

Sorry if you feel this question is silly as I'm quite new

I imported image from web using these commands

```
resp = requests.get('https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ajk2pbTiXf7j_hYsiBm4bwHaHI?pid=ImgDet&rs=1')
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
```

next i transformed it into tensors

Define a transform to convert the image to tensor

```
transform = T.ToTensor()
```

I have also found another code for transformation, and am unsure about which one i should go forward with

```
transform = T.Compose([T.PILToTensor()])
```

could you please suggest which of these transformation is more recommended?
the first one gives floating point o/p and the second one gives 8-bit int o/p

Convert the image to PyTorch tensor

```
tensor = transform(image)
```

Save tensor to inputs folder

```
torch.save(tensor, 'C:/Users/amina/Downloads/ML project/inputs.t')
```

print the converted image tensor

```
print(tensor)
```

now, using the split function i am able to split this image

```
a=torch.split(tensor, 2 , dim=0)
```

What I dont know is how to save these split images into a folder(as shown in the screenshot

[image]

I did that using opencv. where I can view them any time and call them later on in my code?

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate image in Python, I recommend converting it into `numpy` array first. You can then do matrix operations freely.

```py
resp = requests.get('https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ajk2pbTiXf7j_hYsiBm4bwHaHI?pid=ImgDet&rs=1')
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
```

You'll notice it's not array.

```py
print(type(image)) 

<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
```

Now, convert to numpy array,

```py
image = np.array(image)
print(type(image))
print(image.shape))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(456, 474, 3)

# To convert to Tensor,
image = torch.tensor(image)
```

```py
# Split by N*N squares
N = 2

# Image shape
H, W = image.shape[:2]

# Splitted image shape
h = (H/N)
w = (W/N)

for y in range(N):
    y_start = y * h
    y_end = y_start + h

    # Index must be int!
    y_start = int(y_start)
    y_end = int(y_end)

    for x in range(N):
        x_start = x * w
        x_end = x_start + w

        x_start = int(x_start)
        x_end = int(x_end)

        # Here, save the splitted image
        splitted = image[y_start:y_end,x_start:x_end,:]
```

To save Tensor as image file,

```py
transform = T.ToPILImage()
img = transform(splitted)
img.save("image.png")
```

Comment: To read more, check out [NumPy Array Slicing tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp)

Comment: Following your instructions, I am only getting a single portion of the image when I plot the "splitted" variable when i want all the parts of the divided image to be shown as I have shown in the screenshot in the original question. Also, when I go ahead to save the image, i am getting the following error
**ValueError: pic should not have > 4 channels. Got 228 channels.**